# add hash tag to URL on dropdown item select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4

Front end I'm using Backbone and back-end rails.

I have a dropdown list like below

```
<select id="data-source-dropdown">
    <option value="1" <@if(client_type==1){@>selected<@}@>><a href='#adform' >Ad forms</a></option>
    <option value="2" <@if(client_type==2){@>selected<@}@>><a href='#ansform' >Ans form</a></option>
    <option value="3" <@if(client_type==3){@>selected<@}@>><a href='#bform' >B Form</a></option>
</select
```

When i select one of them, i want to display in URL like if `ad form` selects i need `localhost:3000#adform`

which is not displaying using above code

How to do that for drop downs

Is there a way to do it in backbone or rails

Comment: pardon for my ignorance but what syntax is `<@=` ?

Comment: @aelor, that was mistake, edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I just experimented if I can do and it worked, try it.

```
<select id="data-source-dropdown" onchange="append_info()">
  <option value="">Select one--</option>
  <option value="#adform">Ad forms</option>
  <option value="#ansform">Ans form</option>
  <option value="#bform"> B Form</option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure of your rails condition, use `<% %>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function append_info() {
    var val = document.getElementById("data-source-dropdown").value;
    window.history.pushState("", "", window.location.href +  val);
  }
</script>
```

On change `url` keeps appending to the previous ..

use rails condition like this for `selected`

```
 <option value="#adform" <% if condition %> selected <% end %> >Ad forms</option>
```